# Google Map not showing on portrait view iOS 7

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, ios7

I am not sure why the Google Map on this page http://devhost.in/ftmap/ft.html does not show up in portrait view on iPhone (iOS 7). It shows in iOS 6 and other mobile devices.

I have checked the media queries and everything seems fine and the fact that it works on all other devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check line 8624 of all.css, that one is doing the harm:

```
.visual{display:none!important;}
```

Comment: Thank you! But why did it not hide it on iOS6?

Comment: No idea, I don't have iOS6 anymore :)